# Splitting n values into m chunks

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, partitioning

I want to iterate over every possible partition of n integers into m chunks. I can do this by using m nested for-loops but I'm sure theres a better way to do it.

Also it would be helpful if my code could take in m as a variable.

the nested loop code looks something like:

for a1 <- 1 to n {
  for a2 <- a1 to n {
    .
    .
    .
      for am <- a(m-1) to n {
        myFunc(Array[1..n], a1, a2, ..., am)
}}...}}

Comment: Maybe you should post your code.

Comment: Did you try something? If so, do post that code!

Comment: Theres no code really. This is for an algorithms class. I did the above thing after setting m=8. Which was just 8 nested for loops. I just need to call myFunc() on every possible partition

Comment: The word you are looking for is recursion.  Google can take it from there.

Comment: I know I can recurse over it but this is a part of a way bigger algorithm n im trying to make it simpler. Adding another recursive function would mess things up more

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using recursion. But you've mentioned in comments that you can not use recursive solution, so I can suggest another solution - use any method to generate all C(n-1, m-1) combinations (I hope, there are ready-to-use non-recursive combinatorial solutions for Java).

For example, for n = 7, m = 3, you will have C(6,2) = 15 combinations - n stars, n-1 spaces, m-1 of them may stay, other (m-n) will collapse, forming m clusters.

```
*_*_*_*_*_*_*
```

Combination 010001 corresponds to configuration `**_****_*`, or partition 7 = 2 + 4 + 1

Answer (score 0):

When learning to write such programs, there is no substitute for reading Knuth:

http://www.kcats.org/csci/464/doc/knuth/fascicles/fasc3a.pdf